# How to add parameters to a function argument without calling it

Tags: javascript

For example, addEventListener's 2-nd argument has a "e" or "evt" or "event" or "..." parameter. How can I add parameters to a function argument without calling it (without using arguments object). Is it possible?

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [partial functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions with arguments and not provide them. For example,

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

console.log(add(1, 2)); // 3
console.log(add(2));    // NaN (2 + undefined)
console.log(add(0));    // NaN (undefined + undefined)
```

If you don't want the function to return value like `NaN`, you can write this:

```
function add2(x, y) {
    x = x || 0;
    y = y || 0;

    return x + y;
}

console.log(add2(1, 2)); // 3
console.log(add2(2));    // 2
console.log(add2(0));    // 0
```